# TSQL: Need help optimizing this two-part record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to build a view that I can use throughout our system that returns a standardized list of users and their access.

```
Table: Users
UserID    UserName     IsAdmin
----------------------------------
1         John         0
2         Jane         1
3         Mary         0

Table: Clients
ClientID  ParentClientID     ClientName
----------------------------------
1         NULL               Pepsico
2         1                  Pizza Hut
3         1                  Taco Bell
4         1                  KFC
5         NULL               McDonalds

Table: UsersInClients
UserID    ClientID
----------------------------------
1         2
1         3
2         1
3         5
```

My desired output:

```
UserID    ClientID
----------------------------------
1         2 --User 1 & 3 are not admins so list only includes IDs in UsersInClients table.
1         3
2         1 --If Users.IsAdmin = 1, it should return
2         2 --all parent client and all child clients,
2         3 --one row per client like this.
2         4
3         5
```

The only way I can think of doing this is using CTEs and temp tables, cursors, etc, but I was hoping this could be a view so I could join to it in my queries.  Can this be done?

Thanks guys

Comment: FYI you can still do a `CTE` in a view definition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the following way, with a UNION of two queries.

(There may be a way to do this all in a single JOIN condition but this is easier to debug.)

```
SELECT UserId, ClientID
FROM UsersInClients Uic  INNER JOIN Users U ON Uic.UserId = U.UserID
INNER JOIN Clients C ON (C.ClientID = Uic.ClientID OR C.ParentClientID = Uic.ClientID)
WHERE U.IsAdmin = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT UserId, ClientID
FROM UsersInClients Uic  INNER JOIN Users U ON UIC.UserId = U.UserID
INNER JOIN Clients C ON C.ClientID = Uic.ClientID
WHERE U.IsAdmin = 0
```

Comment: Also, you're assuming he client parent-child is only one level deep.  Although it is only one level deep in my example, it could be 5 or even 10 levels deep.

Comment: If you need more than 1 level of hierarchy, then I'd recommend using a Hierarchy type that is native to SQL 2008 or newer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

Comment: Um, I am - if you look above, I have a ClientID and a ParentClientID which are used to represent the hierarchy.  if this column is NULL, it's the top level parent.  I also mention above that tried using CTE's (which the article above mentions), but i'm trying to make a view. If it MUST be a SP, i'm ok with that too

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unbounded hierarchy, your solution is going to be a CTE.

```
WITH T AS 
(
    SELECT UC.UserId, UC.ClientId, U.IsAdmin
    FROM UsersInClient UC
    INNER JOIN Users U
      ON UC.UserId = U.UserId
  UNION ALL
    SELECT T.UserId, C.ClientId, T.IsAdmin
    FROM T
    INNER JOIN Clients C
      ON T.ClientId = C.ParentClientId AND T.IsAdmin = 1
)
SELECT * FROM T
```

And by the way this could be a view.